# SQL Server Varbinary data type in DB2

Tags: sql, sql-server, db2

I have a problem with migrating from SQL Server to IBM DB2 with the following code snippet:

```
CREATE TABLE  fgt_qrtz_job_details (
        sched_name     varchar(200)  not null, 
        job_name       varchar(200)  not null, 
        job_group      varchar(200)  not null, 
        description    varchar(1020) null, 
        job_class_name varchar(1020) not null,
        is_durable  CHAR(1) not null,
        is_nonconcurrent    CHAR(1) not null,
        is_update_data  CHAR(1) not null,
        requests_recovery   CHAR(1) not null,
        job_data varbinary(max) null);
```

The reason is the `varbinary` datatype, I can't find any appropriate type for DB2, maybe you have any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2z9.doc.intro%2Fsrc%2Ftpc%2Fdb2z_largeobjectdatatypes.htm

Comment: Try using BLOB if its a lot of data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well there is a surprise.  Usually DB2 for LUW has features that DB2 for i is missing.  Here is a case of the opposite, so you will have to use a BLOB.